# how to get compile warning

Tags: c++, g++

I'm quite surprised when I compile the following code without any warning using g++ 4.1.2 with -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion enabled.

I want g++ to show me every warning to avoid potential harm. I have to stick to g++ 4.1.2.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint8_t u1=1;
    uint64_t u64=1000;
    string s1="";

    u1=u64; // want warning here
    s1=u64; // want warning here
    s1=u1;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find the English phrase is "want to", not "wanna".

Comment: And you don't want a warning on the last line? What is the intended meaning of assignment from unsigned char to string?

Comment: @David: `string` has `operator=(char)`.

Comment: So you also need `-Wsign-conversion`. I think it's time for `-Wall-but-this-time-for-real`. O my.

Comment: @Georg: thanks I failed to check for that. I have never used it and did not think that would be supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid GCC before 4.3 doesn't seem to support this. The description of `-Wconversion` changed between 4.2 and 4.3 to reflect the new warning behavior, and there is no indication that pre-4.3 GCC would check for this.

Comment: I can confirm it, gcc 4.3 produces warning, 4.2 does not

Comment: I can also confirm GCC 4.4 produces the warning, and only with `-Wconversion`enabled

Comment: Thx. Then I'll have to look for some static c++ code analysis tool.